# How can I randomize flipclock.js so that it's not a countdown but rather random numbers flipping constantly?

Tags: javascript, flipclock

The js script is too long to include in the body but I've included the link for reference. Thanks in advance.

http://flipclockjs.com/

Comment: you can try setting each digit to a random number

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `interval` callback to call setTime and set it to a random time

From the documentation at http://flipclockjs.com/

> **interval**
>   This callback is triggered with each interval of the timer

> **setTime()**
>   This method will set the clock time after it has been instantiated just call > the .setTime() method on an FlipClock object.